# Read Gzip Header in HttpClient

Tags: c#

I set `Gzip` header in my request and response send it with `Gzip` too. and havent problem with reading a data. but need check the server Send me `Gzip` header or not.

I can see `Content-Encoding: gzip` header when send request with `HttpWebRequest`.

How can see `Content-Encoding: gzip` header when send request with `httpClient`?
I check it both `HttpResponseHeaders` and `HttpContentHeaders` but not find it this header.

`ContentEncoding` in `HttpContentHeaders` is empty too.

Comment: `HttpClient` does this automatically, while `HttpWebRequest` requires you to manually add the "Accept-Encoding" header. If you don't see the "Accept-Encoding" header in the request sent by HttpClient, it's likely that the header is added automatically and you don't need to worry about it. As in you wont need to wire up a unzipping library or anything like that, its done out-of-the-box.

Comment: I know that, but I don't have a problem with it. I need this header for something else

Comment: Then use a HttpWebRequest, or flag it the body or query string.

Comment: this mean, I cant get this header from `httpClient` ?

Comment: So you've definitely added it? `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); and httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
`

Comment: i add it this header in my request.
some websites need i send them request. i need check if there not use gzip format reject it them.